# How to store controllers global variable datas in common function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have many $scope variables in controllers. How to put everything in a common file and how to use it?

**1. FirstController.js :**

```js
        $rootScope.page = "First-page";
        $scope.search = '';
        $rootScope.previous_page = "";
        $rootScope.getSearchCard = [];
```

**2.SecondController.js:**

```js
        $scope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.page = "second-page";
        $scope.activeTab = 'second';
        $scope.search = '';
        $scope.isActiveClass = '';
        $scope.active = '';
        $scope.tabTitle = '';
        $scope.dimension = [];
        $scope.detailsArray = [];
        $scope.details = [];
        $scope.cards = [];
```

**3. ThirdController.js :**

```js
        $rootScope.page = "third-page";
        $rootScope.previous_page = "second-page";
        $rootScope.getSearchCard = [];        
        $scope.resultsArray = [];
        $scope.active = 0;
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;
        $scope.isShow = false;
        $scope.showSelectAll = true;
        $scope.searchCards = false;
        $scope.selectedCards = [];
        $scope.totalRelated = [];
```

Like this in every controller i am using variable. Instead of using in controllers i need to add everything in common file and i need to use it in respective controllers.

Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

**4.commonService.js :**

```js
abbvieapp.factory('commonService', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', '$state', '$window',
        function($timeout, $rootScope,$state, $window) {

            var getUserInfo = function(scope) {
              'page' : $rootScope.page = "first-page";
              'page' :  $rootScope.page = "second-page";
              'page' : $rootScope.page = "third-page";
              'search' :  scope.search = '';
              'previous_page' :  $rootScope.previous_page = "";
              'getSearchCard' :  $rootScope.getSearchCard = [];
            }
            return {
                'getUserInfo': getUserInfo
            }
```

**And in second controller $scope.active is string and in third controller $scope.active is integer. How can I handle this?  **

**And how can I come to know this is First-Page, Second-Page and Third-Page**

Comment: This is what a service can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service and store everything there:

```
myModule.factory('dataService', function() {
  return {
     search: '',
     previous_page: '',
     ...
  }
});
```

Then you can inject your service into each controller. Check the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for more info.

Comment: Here how to know first or second or third page? and $scope.active is both integer and string in respective third and second controller

Comment: You can update the page at the beginning of each controller (dataService.page = {page}). One of the active fields should be renamed to something else if you want to have them both in the same place.